# AppSync HTTP API

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

Guys I'm at my wits end here, need some help. I'm trying out Appsync and building out a GraphQL where the resolver for one of my fields pulls data from an external API.

Here's a brief structure of the raw API response from the server:

```
{
  total: 1000,
  result: [
     {address: 'xyz', name: 'abc'}, {address: 'def', name: 'uvw'}
  ]
}
```

I have a GraphQL Type defined as:

```
Address @model {
address: String! @primaryKey
name: String!
}
```

I created a resolver on "address" based on a HTTP endpoint data source. I believe that is configured properly.

Here is my request mapping functions that are part of the resolver:

```
#**
Make an arbitrary HTTP call when this field is listed in a query selection set.
The "relativePath" is the resource path relative to the root URL provided when you
created the HTTP data source. Pass a "params" object to forward headers, body,
and query parameters to the HTTP endpoint.
*#
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "method": "GET",
  "resourcePath": "/dev/v2/${context.args.address}",
  "params":{
      "headers": {
          "x-api-key": "xxxxxx"
      }
  }
}
```

And response mapping:

```
## Raise a GraphQL field error in case of a datasource invocation error
#if($ctx.error)
  $util.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end
## If the response is not 200 then return an error. Else return the body **
#if($ctx.result.statusCode == 200)
    $util.toJson($ctx.result.body.result)
#else
    $utils.appendError($ctx.result.body, "$ctx.result.statusCode")
#end
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this does not work in returning query data from the graphQL. I've spent 8 hours trying to figure it out and pretty sure it's something really obvious. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - I had put the resolver on the "Address" type fields vs. the query type fields.